# libhwloc.so.5 error while installing vortex

Tags: llvm, opencl, gpgpu, pocl

While trying 'make' in vortex after installing all the dependencies, I get the following error:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: libhwloc.so.5, needed by /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
    /usr/bin/ld: /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_topology_load'
    /usr/bin/ld: /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_get_api_version'
    /usr/bin/ld: /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_get_nbobjs_by_depth'
    /usr/bin/ld: /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_topology_destroy'
    /usr/bin/ld: /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_bitmap_isequal'
    /usr/bin/ld: /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_topology_ignore_type'
    /usr/bin/ld: /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_get_type_depth'
    /usr/bin/ld: /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_get_obj_by_depth'
    /usr/bin/ld: /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_topology_init'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I attempted by installing the hwloc library (v1.10) and setting the library path for it, but, I am still encountering the following error:

```
    `/opt/pocl/compiler/bin/poclcc: error while loading shared libraries: libhwloc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    make[3]: *** [../common.mk:76: kernel.pocl] Error 127
    make[2]: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [Makefile:11: opencl] Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2`
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question, I tried to install hwloc v2.40 and maunally to create a link which can solve the link issue, but the new issue was raised that show as below:

> /usr/bin/ld: /opt/pocl/runtime/lib/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_topology_ignore_type'. But` hwloc_topology_ignore_type' was supported from v0.9.3. I am not sure if it was deleted. Just share info. no solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question when using the `ubunutu/bionic` toolchain of vortex in Ubuntu 22.04 (wsl2).

This problem **can be simply solved by switching to** `ubuntu/focal` toolchain. Just change the variable `OSDIR` and `OS` would be OK (in `toolchain_install.sh` and `toolchain_env.sh`)

**Probable Reason**: default version of `hwloc`'s so file in *Ubuntu18.04* may be `libhwloc.so.5` ( and `libhwloc.so.15` in *20.04*, `libhwloc.so.15.5.2` in *22.04*. You can see them in dir `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` after using `apt install libhwloc-dev` ), and variable `hwloc_topology_ignore_type` was removed in the recent two versions.